# Accessing objects from one class to another in ES6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, es6-class

First of all apology for asking this as I am new to ES6 javascript. My class structure is something like -

Filename - Ab.js

```
class A{
method A(){
const a = '1'
//could have more const in this method
```

}}

```
class B{
method B(){
const b='2' 
//could have more const in this method
}}
```

Now I want to access this class in another files say C.js

```
class c{
 method c()
{
      //here I want to access A and B like
    const c= A.A.a // this should return 1
 }}
```

However I tried by exporting the default class in Ab.js and importing the same in C.js, I was able to access the value of the object in C.js but if you have multiple classes in Ab.js, it is not allowed. May I know why ? .. any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: you should use [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) keyword

Comment: how will that help @guijob ...you can't access `const a` inside `method A` regardless

Comment: Basic concepts of scope still apply whether it's ES6 or not. As written you have no access to `const a` or `const b` from outside those methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use static methods and return an object:

```
class A {
  static A(a = 1, b = 2) {
    return { a, b };
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
A.A().a; // 1
A.A().b; // 2
```

Comment: sorry, I just edited my function, I could have more than 1 const in my method in base class

Comment: Then add more properties to the returned object.

Comment: yes @JackBashford - do you mean like this class A {
  static A(a = 1, b=2) {
    return { a, b };
  }
}

Comment: Yes exactly @Prany

Comment: cheers mate @JackBashford, let me try and I'll get back here to you

Comment: No problem @Prany, always glad to help.

Comment: @JackBashford - Do I have to give some reference as well in class C as I'm getting reference error that A is not defined ?

Comment: I messed something yesterday and this is the right answer.

Comment: No worries @Prany, always glad to help.